# Customized transformation of a selection in VSCode without writing an extension

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode to format snippets of code (code fences) in online quizzes in the GIFT format (which is a kind of markdown for quizzes). To properly format the code for the quizzes, it's necessary to apply several steps:

1. Escape all special characters in the selection (e.g., `{` -> `\{`, `=` -> `\=`, etc.)
2. Convert line breaks to literal `\n` in the text (line breaks have a meaning in the quiz format)
3. Replace `\n`  with `\n_` (where _ is a non-breaking space)
4. Add fence delimiters ``` at the start and end of the code
5. etc.

I'm pretty sure I can do each of these as a find/replace with regex, but I wanted to know if it's possible to use vanilla VSCode to record them or make them into a macro of sorts.

I looked at snippets, and I've used them before, but this doesn't seem to apply (at least I couldn't see a way).

I looked at code formatters, and it seems not to be a use case for it. The code examples I want to format could be in any language. It's more about making sure the format of the code fence (the final result) is compatible with the quiz markdown (escaping special characters, encoding newlines as `\n` and preserving indentation with non-breaking spaces).

In other editors, it might be a "macro" feature (one that can be recorded and played back). But it's [not yet there in VSCode](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/4490).

Is it possible to apply all these steps to a selection without writing an extension?

Comment: It would honestly be easier to write an extension for this.

Comment: maybe you can use [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) in combi with [Replace Rules](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bhughes339.replacerules)

Comment: @rioV8 I was able to do it with just [Replace Rules](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bhughes339.replacerules). It has a feature to define aggregate rules `replacerules.rulesets` to apply, and it works great (as long as everything is a find/replace in regex). I didn't figure out yet how to map this to a hot key, but it's not a big deal.

Comment: on the doc page is an example key-binding

Comment: @rioV8 yes, once I got a keybindings file I could customize, it was easy. Thanks!